# cordova-plugin-file: deviceready event not fired after 5 seconds

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-5.0.0, cordova-plugin-file

When I install cordova-plugin-file I get this error. The error seems to trace all the way back to version 1.3 back in 2014...

```
deviceready event not fired after 5 seconds
```

How is it still happening in version 2.1.0 and Cordova 5? I downgraded version by version and it only stopped showing the error in 1.1, but then I get a different error from cordova.js (understandably since it's so far ahead of that build).

```
module cordova-plugin-file.ProgressEvent not found
```

I can't even find the issue tracker for the plugin. What's a developer to do?

Comment: provide some code please, i just tested it in a blank project with this plugin only and `deviceReady` was fired.

Comment: deviceready maybe not fired because of a javascript error somewhere? have you checked the console logs?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention this happens only when run on an iOS device.

Comment: What code would you like to see? I haven't written any code for the plugin yet. I just added it to see the problem and the problem goes away if I remove it. All the other code in app.js is standard ionic/angular startup code. It works in the browser but not on iOS 8.4 device

Answer (score 1):

#### I had the same problem:

> Uncaught module cordova-plugin-file.ProgressEvent not found

The plugins weren't added to the app's plugins folder and config.xml for some mysterious reason. I had installed the cordova-plugin-file-transfer plugin before I got the error above.

#### My solution:

Delete the platform (Android for example) folder in the platforms folder. After adding the platform again the error was gone.